# Laravel claims that the running query is not running

Tags: eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-9

I have a query

```
$MakinelerQuery = Makineler::
leftjoin('users as u','u.id','makineler.yetkilisi')
->leftjoin('oyunlar as o','o.id','makineler.oyun_id')
->leftjoin('sifre_hareket as sh','sh.makine_id','makineler.id');
$MakinelerQuery = $MakinelerQuery->select('makineler.*','u.user_name','o.oyun_adi');
$MakinelerQuery = $MakinelerQuery->selectRaw('max(sh.sifre_tarihi) as maxSifreTarihi');
$MakinelerQuery = $MakinelerQuery->groupby('makineler.id');

$fetchMakineler = $MakinelerQuery->get();
```

As a result, Laravel creates a sql like this and also gives me an error.

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'gameworld_db.makineler.makine_adi' isn't in GROUP BY`
[image]

When I take this sql, copy it to phpmyadmin and run it, `it works` fine!!! (exactly what I wanted)

i don't understand what is the problem?

Comment: I did not give details to the question here, because what I am wondering is why the normally working query does not work in Laravel. This is the gist of the question. actually working means there are no syntax errors. Saying that there is no missing field in the database etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario the answer was pretty simple.

In Laravel 9.0 `config\database.php` --> find the paragraph `"mysql" array`

Set `'strict' => false` to disable all.

so if you have a query that includes groupby and you are going to group by selecting a single field, you should set strict to false.